# Multiline edit using occur

Tags: occur

Is it possible to use `occur` or something else to edit multiple lines of code within a certain tag. For example:

```
#*
some code
some more code
#*
```

I've tried using occur, but it edits only the first line -- the line that gets a line number. In multiline match, the rest of the lines don't get a line number.

Basic example, I've tried using occur interactively for this:

```
#*
p
#*
```

`M-x occur` then `#*C-qC-jpC-qC-j#*`:

```
30:#*
  :p
  :#*
```

Then `e` in occur mode and `C-c C-c` to finish editing. Only the edits on the first line with line number 30 got passed on to the source file.